# PowerShell foreach loop in AWX/Ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible, ansible-awx

I've recently deployed a POC automation platform involving ServiceNow and AWX. I have a use case to automate access to windows servers.

The ServiceNow form will be supplying me 10 windows server names at a time.

I did write this PowerShell script to handle multiple computer objects and it works as expected when I run it directly on Windows. It does prompt me for multiple computer names and does the work as expected. But when I put the same script on AWX it does not recognize the `$Computer` variable which is a sort of dynamic variable. Here is the script.

```
function Set-AccessOnRemoteMachine {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [string]$User,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [String]$Group,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [String]$AccessType
    )

    if (($AccessType -eq 'Grant') -and ($Group -eq 'Remote Desktop Users')) {
        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
            if ((Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { HOSTNAME }) -eq "$Computer" ) {
                Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { param($Group, $User) net localgroup $Group $User /add } -ArgumentList $Group, $User
                Write-Output "Successfully added the user $User in the Group $Group on the computer $Computer"
            } else {
                Write-Output "$Computer is not reachble"
            }
        }
    } elseif (($AccessType -eq 'Grant') -and ($Group -eq 'Administrators')) {
        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
            if ((Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { HOSTNAME }) -eq "$Computer" ) {
                Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { param($Group, $User) net localgroup $Group $User /add } -ArgumentList $Group, $User
                Write-Output "Successfully added the user $User in the Group $Group on the computer $Computer"
            } else {
                Write-Output "$Computer is not reachble"
            }
        }
    } elseif (($AccessType -eq 'Revoke') -and ($Group -eq 'Remote Desktop Users')) {
        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
            if ((Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { HOSTNAME }) -eq "$Computer" ) {
                Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { param($Group, $User) net localgroup $Group $User /delete } -ArgumentList $Group, $User
                Write-Output "Successfully added the user $User in the Group $Group on the computer $Computer"
            } else {
                Write-Output "$Computer is not reachble"
            }
        }
    } elseif (($AccessType -eq 'Revoke') -and $Group -eq ('Administrators')) {
        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
            if ((Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { HOSTNAME }) -eq "$Computer" ) {
                Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { param($Group, $User) net localgroup $Group $User /delete } -ArgumentList $Group, $User
                Write-Output "Successfully added the user $User in the Group $Group on the computer $Computer"
            } else {
                Write-Output "$Computer is not reachble"
            }
        }
    }
}

Set-AccessOnRemoteMachine -ComputerName $Computer -Group $Group -User $User -AccessType $AccessType
```

Here is the error that I get in AWX.

```
Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to
pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects instead of
strings.
At C:\temp\Set-AccessOnRemoteMachine.ps1:28 char:9
+ Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { param($ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.String[]:String[]) [Invoke-Command], ArgumentException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionInvalidComputerName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Please help me understand how to handle PowerShell foreach loop in AWX and Ansible Core.

Comment: What about the error is not clear? You're passing an invalid computer name. We can't tell you what about that value is incorrect since you chose to not disclose the value you're passing.